# Select Last value from a specific field in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to write a script in SQL Server which display the output table.

Input table

```
Name    CompanyName   ContractCode   ContractEndDate
----------------------------------------------------
 A      B&D              A1          2016 08 31
 B      B&D              B1          2016 09 01
 B      B&D              C1          2016 09 02
 B      B&D              D1          2016 09 03
 C      B&D              E1          2016 09 04
 C      B&D              F1          2016 09 05
 C      B&D              G1          2016 09 06
 C      B&D              H1          2016 09 07
```

Output should be like:

```
Name    CompanyName    ContractCode    ContractEndDate
------------------------------------------------------
 A      B&D               A1           2016 08 31
 B      B&D               D1           2016 09 03
 D      B&D               H1           2016 09 07
```

I want a SQL script that displays the desired output.

Comment: Presumably the last row in the desired results should be "C" and not "D".

Comment: What is the **logic** behind what you want?? Please **explain** - don't just leave us guessing....

Answer (score 4):

The standard method is to use `row_number()`:

```
select Name, CompanyName, ContractCode, ContractEndDate
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by Name order by ContractEndDate desc) as seqnum 
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `CTE` :

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
     SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name  ORDER BY ContractEndDate DESC) AS RN
     FROM Inputtable
     ) 

 SELECT Name, CompanyName, ContractCode, ContractEndDate
 FROM CTE
 WHERE RN=1
```